# in Steema TeeChart - line chart, if add datetime in xAxis , axis legend text shows 2 times

Tags: linechart, teechart

in Steema TeeChart - line chart, if add datetime in xAxis, axis legend text shows 2 times (refer Image1.png), Here is my code

**

```
foreach (HeatunitGraph item in graphdata)
{ 
    dc = Convert.ToDouble (item.Value);
    currentline.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(item.ActionDate), dc);
}
```

**

also i want show a line in current date. exactly what i need is (ref Image2.png)
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set your desired bottom axis increment. Otherwise it will be automatic. You can set it to one day like this:

```
 tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Increment = Steema.TeeChart.Utils.GetDateTimeStep(Steema.TeeChart.DateTimeSteps.OneDay);
```

Comment: Hi Narcis, its helpful thanks. How to show line in Current date with given value. (Please refer above image)

Comment: Hi, i got solution for the above problem. i just add another Series for it.

How can format the date from 5/25/2013 to 25/05/2013 ?

Comment: @Ramesh you should set tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Labels.DateTimeFormat = "dd/MMMM/yyyy"; For more axis related information please have a look at Tutorial 4. Tutorials can be found at TeeChart's program group.